# Access objects own key-value that is within an array

Tags: javascript

I know variations of this question have been asked but bear with me.

I have the following array containing objects (which are routines):

```
const PREMADE_ROUTINES = [
  {
    itemIds: ['makebed', 'drinkwater', 'quickstretch', 'hotshower',  'brushteeth', 'smallsnack', 'getdressed', 'todolist', 'declutterinbox',],
    routineDuration: DEFAULT_ROUTINE_ITEMS.getItemsFromIds(PASS THIS OBJECTS itemIds HERE)
  }
]
```

How could I access the `itemIds` in this case within each of the objects in the `PREMADE_ROUTINES` array?

In this case, I would need to pass the objects `itemIds` as an argument to the function. I could do this if the object wasn't in an array with a `get()`. However, I don't know how to do it in this case. Any ideas?

Ideally, I would like to simply access the `routineDuration` key by looping and simply accessing it.

Comment: You might want to give each `itemId` its own function: `{ itemId: 'makebed', routineDuration: DEFAULT_DURATION } ` ... etc, as this might be more ergonomic to work with.

Comment: Make `routineDuration` a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get). Possible duplicate of [Self-references in object literals / initializers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literals-initializers)

Comment: @Rajesh but I would like to access it without having to loop. I would like the key to calc its value on the go without having to do anything else.

Comment: Try `routineDuration: DEFAULT_ROUTINE_ITEMS.getItemsFromIds(PREMADE_ROUTINES[0].itemIds)`. You may have to use `var` instead of `const`

Comment: @TylerRoper yeah and how do you access the object?? it is not the same question... I can't do `foo.getItemIds` because foo is within an array!

Comment: @WalterMonecke I suppose I'm confused, as you yourself said *"Ideally, I would like to simply access the routineDuration key **by looping and simply accessing it**"*. So... loop through `PREMADE_ROUTINES` as you would any other array, and for each item, access the `routineDuration` property.

Comment: @TylerRoper yes, but I was meaning when rendering the items say in a component. My question is specifically if this can be done by referencing the object itself - like with a `get()`. I clearly show what my question is about in the code.

Comment: It's about as clear as mud. `get routineDuration() { return DEFAULT_ROUTINE_ITEMS.getItemsFromIds(this.itemIds); }` ... `PREMADE_ROUTINES.forEach(i => console.log(i.routineDuration));` - Is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/69Lkaqdr/) not what you're after?

Answer (score 0):

In your particular context the best solution is to break away the `itemIds` declaration. This is so you don't run into `this` issues when populating it later on.

```js
    const DEFAULT_ROUTINES = [
        ...
    ]

    const PREMADE_ROUTINES = [ {
    itemIds: DEFAULT_ROUTINES,
    routineDuration: yourFunctionHere(DEFAULT_ROUTINES)

]}
```

I notice your data structure is a bit complex. It might be worth refactoring it, and introducing a couple utility / filtering methods to make your life easier in the future.

Comment: Yes, this is my plan B, but I still think its cleaner if I could reference it with some getter somehow :/

Answer (score 0):

You could create a method returning your routines object. That way it'd be more reusable.

```
const createRoutine = (routines) => ({
    itemIds: routines,
    routineDurations: getRoutineDurations(routines)
});

const PREMADE_ROUTINES = [
    createRoutine(['makebed', 'drinkwater', 'quickstretch']),
    createRoutine(['hotshower',  'brushteeth', 'smallsnack']),
];
```